# How to avoid losing values with List's

Tags: c#, methods, reference, tuples, reference-type

I have the following method :

```
private static Tuple<List<int>, bool> GetTurns(List<int> possibleTurns, IList<int> currentLine)
{
    List<int> localPossibleTurns = possibleTurns;

    foreach (var passedTurn in passedTurns)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < localPossibleTurns.Count; j++)
        {
            int indexOfNewNumber = currentLine.IndexOf(localPossibleTurns[j]);

            if (localPossibleTurns[j] == passedTurn.Item1)
            {
                if (indexOfNewNumber + 1 == passedTurn.Item2 || indexOfNewNumber == passedTurn.Item2)
                {
                    localPossibleTurns.RemoveAt(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return localPossibleTurns.Count == 0
            ? new Tuple<List<int>, bool>(localPossibleTurns, false)
            : new Tuple<List<int>, bool>(localPossibleTurns, true);
}
```

and using it at this line :

```
if (!GetTurns(possibleRoutes, secondLine).Item2)
{
    //do something
}
```

whenever it reaches that point it passes the `possibleRoutes` List into the method and since the list is reference type whenever a value is removed from the one declared in the method `GetTurns` - `localPossibleTurns` same happens to the `possibleRoutes` list. How can I avoid this and change the values of `possibleRoutes` only when I do `possibleRoutes = GetTurns(possibleRoutes, secondLine).Item1;` ?

Comment: Imo a `GetXY...` method that modifies a passed list is not good design. If i want to _get_ something i don't expect that anything is modified there.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That's exactly what they're trying to prevent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assigning it to a new variable does not create a new list. If you want a copy you can use `possibleTurns.ToList()` or better `new List<int>(possibleTurns)`. I prefer the latter for readability regarding object creation and because someday the might change the code of ToList() for performance gains to first check the type and then perform a simple cast.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable is List<T>)
        return (List<T>) enumerable;
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the collection passed in as a parameter.

You can create a new collection to work with inside the method using Linq ToList:

```
List<int> localPossibleTurns = possibleTurns.ToList();
```